# Simple Motor Wiring

Tags: wiring

I have a small .5 hp motor I am trying to get running. I received it with a couple of the wires disconnected. The company isn't very helpful. I have attached a picture. What is the correct wiring for this item? How do I figure out the correct wiring for the capacitor with no attached diagram? What wires should be connected together for a 100v, 60hz operation? The wires from the windings are black, blue and yellow.

[image]

Comment: please post pictures of any labels that are attached to the motor

Comment: the black wire appears to have solder at its end .... do any of the other wires have traces of solder on them? (not counting the white wire, of course)

Answer (score 2):

### Figure out the motor wires

Start out by measuring the resistance of the motor windings.  This will tell you which motor wire is which.  Using an ohm meter (or multimeter set to ohms), measure the resistance between each set of motor wires (Bl1 -> Y, Bl2 -> Y, Bl1 -Bl2).

The lowest resistance measurement will be the Run winding. Meaning you're measuring between Common (C) and Run (R). You'll get the highest measurement when you're measuring across the Start and Run windings. And you'll get the middlest measurement when you're measuring the Start (S) winding.

So let's say you get the lowest reading between the Yellow wire, and one of the Blue wires.  You get the medium reading between the Yellow wire, and the other Blue wire.  In this case, the Yellow wire is Common (C), Blue(low) is Run (R), and Blue(high) is Start (S).

Once you figure out which wire is which, label them R, S, and C.

### Connect the capacitor

For capacitor start motors, you'll want to have the capacitor in series with the Start (S) winding. So you'll connect one of the capacitor wires to the Start (S) motor wire.

There's likely a centrifugal switch within the motor, that will disconnect the Start winding once the motor gets going.

### Connect the power supply

To get the motor to run, you have to send power through both windings and the capacitor.  Connect one of the power wires to the Common (C) motor wire.  Next, connect the unused capacitor wire, and the Run (R) motor wire to the unused power wire.

The compete circuit should look something like this.

[image: Simple Single Phase Capacitor Start Motor diagram]

If I had to guess at the colors in this motor, I'd guess you'll end up with wiring like this.

[image: Simple Single Phase Capacitor Start Motor diagram with color]